# Update stored procedure in mysql does not work with asp.net?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

Here's my code :

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pass1.Text != pass2.Text)
        {
            lblerror.Text = "Passwords do not match.";
        }
        else
        {
            DB db = new DB();
            string pass = db.Encrypt(pass2.Text.Trim());
            MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(db.sqlstring());
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("changepassword", sqlcon);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(@"pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(@"user1", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = Convert.ToInt16(Session["userKey"]);
                sqlcon.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //Response.Redirect("regex.aspx", false);
                //Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblerror.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlcon.Close();
                Session.Abandon();
                Session.RemoveAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

and My stored procedure is like this.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `changepassword`(IN pass varchar(100),IN user1 varchar(100))
begin
update users set Password = 'pass' where UserID = user1;
end;
```

When I update using call in mysql workbench it works well.

But when I call from backend in asp.net

The value of password is changed 'pass' in table but not actual value which is passed as 'string = pass';

What is wrong in my code? I didn't find any exception in above code.

Comment: You @ sysmbol while adding parameter should be inside the double quotes `cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass;` and you are setting the value of password to "pass" inside your stored procedure. you need to set it to the input parameter `pass`

Comment: I tried with that also, still same.

Comment: you have hardcoded the value inside update statement. Use this `update users set Password = pass where UserID = user1;`

Comment: what's this `Password = 'pass'`?

Comment: I didn't see that. Thanks. Now it works.

Comment: and also @jned29

Comment: Can anyone post as answer?